# Googlebot is adding prefix end of domain /?whateveryouwritehere with http status 200

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

From the server logs i have recently noticed that googlebot getting http status 200 response for non existing URI

```
https://turkishclassified.com/?KKId=3914
https://turkishclassified.com/?KKId=4031
https://turkishclassified.com/?KKId=2890
```

However non-existent other URI without the /? returns the http status 404 and is correct response.

```
https://turkishclassified.com/KKId=3914
https://turkishclassified.com/KKId=4031
https://turkishclassified.com/KKId=2890
```

I am running Plesk that has htaccess file. I also have the following htaccess in public folder by theme developers

```
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can we give correct http status response for existing and non-existing URI. Thks for any replies.

Comment: Your first set of URLs is just pointing to the domain root index (which always kinda “exists”) with a query string added, whereas the second set is using different _paths_ (so the check if it matches an existing folder or file can work for those.) You could either create a RewriteCond / RewriteRule combination that 404s all requests for the root index page that has anything in the query string (if you don’t need the query string there _at all_), or you will have to handle this from within your index.php.

Comment: @04FS Thanks your reply. I also have a redirect for anything after /

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

So how can it be modified to also redirect /?

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following to https://example.com/robots.txt that google follows

```
Disallow: /?KKId=
Disallow: /?bid=
Disallow: /?Ino=
Disallow: /en/search?KKId=
Disallow: /search?KKId=
```

This has worked so far for the crawling part.